# Silverstripe 4 - TreeDropdownField not displaying in CMS

Tags: silverstripe-4

Upgrading a 3.5 site to 4.x. I have the following extension:

```
class BrandExtension extends DataExtension {

    private static $has_one = array(
        "BrandPage" => BrandPage::class
    );                

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
        parent::updateCMSFields($fields);

        $mic = new TreeDropdownField("BrandPageID", "Select portfolio page to link to", SiteTree::class);

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $mic, 'Content');

    }

}
```

This is namespaced, so I updated the config.yml inclusion for this:

```
Vendor\Project\MicrositePage:
  extensions:
    - Vendor\Project\BrandExtension
```

After a Dev/build, the field seems to want to display, but it only shows the label.

[image]

I tried changing the format of the constructor. The 4.0 docs suggest that the above is the correct format however. And changing the constructor didn't do anything.

```
$mic = TreeDropdownField::create("BrandPageID", "Select portfolio page to link to", SiteTree::class);
```

Inspecting the page shows me something is being injected there.

```
<div class="TreeDropdownField treedropdown single searchable searchable" id="Form_EditForm_BrandPageID" data-schema="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;BrandPageID&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;Form_EditForm_BrandPageID&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;text&quot;,&quot;schemaType&quot;:&quot;SingleSelect&quot;,&quot;component&quot;:&quot;TreeDropdownField&quot;,&quot;holderId&quot;:&quot;Form_EditForm_BrandPageID_Holder&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Select portfolio page to link to&quot;,&quot;source&quot;:null,&quot;extraClass&quot;:&quot;treedropdown single searchable&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:null,&quot;rightTitle&quot;:null,&quot;leftTitle&quot;:null,&quot;readOnly&quot;:false,&quot;disabled&quot;:false,&quot;customValidationMessage&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;validation&quot;:[],&quot;attributes&quot;:[],&quot;autoFocus&quot;:false,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;urlTree&quot;:&quot;admin\/pages\/edit\/EditForm\/153\/field\/BrandPageID\/tree&quot;,&quot;showSearch&quot;:true,&quot;emptyString&quot;:&quot;(Choose Page)&quot;,&quot;hasEmptyDefault&quot;:false,&quot;multiple&quot;:false}}" data-state="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;BrandPageID&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;Form_EditForm_BrandPageID&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:0,&quot;message&quot;:null,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;cacheKey&quot;:&quot;2018-03-06 03:43:41&quot;,&quot;showSelectedPath&quot;:false}}">
<input id="Form_EditForm_BrandPageID" type="hidden" name="BrandPageID" value="0">
```

Done multiple dev builds. Tried flushing the CMS. Even hard deleted the SS cache under /tmp. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found that logging out of the CMS and back in again caused the field to display. Although it does appear to be a bit touchy. A couple of times I have refreshed my CMS page and it has disappeared on load.